# Performance Issue on Pentaho Transformation

Tags: performance

We are trying to load 20 million records from Source to Target DB with Insert/Update logic.

for to define insert/update, we have database lookup and compare the record, if it's exists, we will validate MD5 values between source and target, then we will update or insert the records.

Job is running in Pentaho 2 hrs of time and same code in Informatica, its completing in 10 mins.

Can Someone let me know is there anyway we can implement above scenario with better performance.